# Rails 3 - Testing controller's GET method - trying to use JSON and getting 406 errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, automated-tests

I have a simple controller that specifies:

```
respond_to :json
```

When I try to build a functional test that calls it like this:

```
test "GET" do
  get 'index', :format => :json
end
```

Everything works just fine.  If, however, I try to pass a query parameter in like this:

```
test "GET" do
  get 'index', {:my_param = '1234'}, :format => :json
end
```

I get a 406 error returned from the controller.  If I dump the response via `response.inspect`, I can see that the `@status = 406` and the `@header` has a content-type of `text/html`.  If I dump the response via `response.inspect` for the simple case that doesn't pass a query parameter, I see that the `@header` has a content-type of `application/json` as I request in the code.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm suspecting that I'm screwing up ruby syntax with hashes or something but I'm bumping my head against the wall and not getting anywhere.

I'm on a Mac running Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.0.5.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the function you are calling:

```
get(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
```

The `:format` part is still a parameter, certainly not a session or flash. Try:

```
get 'index', {:my_param => '1234', :format => :json}
```

Oh, important note, use '=>', not '=' ... that's a hash, not an assignment.